# Changing frames in layoutAttributesForElements slow down animation

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a custom CollectionViewFlowLayout in which I override `layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect)` in order to get the elements positioned like in the design specs.

Everything is fine, but in some cases, to make a "selection mode" animation, I need to update the y position of the frames, but when I do that, my animation suffers a small delay.

If I maintain the y position and update the x, the width and the height of the attribute, the animation is ok.

Why does that happen? How could I avoid it?

Here's a mockup of my layout:

[image: mockup of layout]

And here's the selected mode:

[image: selected mode]

Basically my animation consists in changing the transform for the visible cells, in a way to make them smaller but centered, and to maintain the alignments and correct spacing I manipulate the frames in layoutAttributesForElements and invalidate the layout.

edit:

- other solutions like changing the cellSize and minimumInteritemSpacing doesn't work for me because UICollectionView animation for cellSize change is extremely wonky

Comment: I'm not how you are animating this layout change, but I was able to get a pretty smooth implementation by just altering item sizes as appropriate and calling invalidateLayout() in an animation block. It seems like you are doing more work than you need to here. I made a test project here https://github.com/edmonston/test-cvlo/ and here's a video https://github.com/edmonston/test-cvlo/blob/master/demo.mov?raw=true

Comment: Seems nice, I'll try out this

Comment: It kind of works, but it doesn't solve my original issue. You only change the spacing between items, but not the spacing from the screen edge. I modified your code to set the contentInset of the UICollectionView, but now I have to remove that inset from the cellSize, otherwise it will break the layout. In your example the calculation is simple, but in my case, I don't know at that point how many cells I have per row, so it's not possible for me to calculate this and return the correct item size. That's why I use a custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Comment: Forget almost everything that I said, I DO have the number of cells per row, I made some further changes on your idea but now it's work very well! And I got to throw away all that custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout code, thanks!

Comment: Please add an answer so I can accept it

Comment: Glad it worked for you! Added an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned up in the comments, there seems to be an easier approach: I was able to get a pretty smooth implementation by just altering the values returned from `collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)`, `collectionView(_:layout:minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt:)` and `collectionView(_:minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt:)` as appropriate, and calling `invalidateLayout()` and `layoutIfNeeded()` inside an animation block at the right moment.

The return values for a really basic layout of items might look like this (where `separatorSize(isInSelectionMode:)` returns larger or smaller values depending on the selection state):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let totalRowHeight: CGFloat = 100
    let widthRatio: CGFloat
    switch indexPath.item % 4 {
    case 0, 3: widthRatio = (2.0 / 3.0)
    case 1, 2: widthRatio = (1.0 / 3.0)
    default: widthRatio = 1.0
    }
    return CGSize(width: (collectionView.bounds.width - separatorSize(isInSelectionMode: selectionMode).width) * widthRatio,
                  height: totalRowHeight - separatorSize(isInSelectionMode: selectionMode).height)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return separatorSize(isInSelectionMode: selectionMode).height
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return separatorSize(isInSelectionMode: selectionMode).width
}
```

Then you just toggle `selectionMode` inside an animation block while invalidating the layout.

I made a [demo project here](https://github.com/edmonston/test-cvlo/) and a [demo video here](https://github.com/edmonston/test-cvlo/blob/master/demo.mov?raw=true).